# Underbrace and text?

Tags: text-manipulation

I want to use text under an equation. I am using the `\underbrace_{text{}}`. My point is that the text is quite long and I want to make it into two lines. For example:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9}_{\text{Aggregate \\ factor payments}} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

So in my example ideally I want the "factor payments" terms to appear below the term "Aggregate". I tried in the way I have in the code, but it did not worked.

Any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. Use `_{\substack{\text{Aggregate}\\\text{factor payments}}}`